# Record-Trigger flow run when Delete error

Tags: visual-workflow, delete, recordtriggeredflow

I'm trying to create a record-trigger flow on Asset delete. I tried getting CV value by formula but the related Account record
is not returning correct value.

I also tried get Account record separately but seem like the flow
is the problem.
The {!Record.Account.Current_Value__pc} should return 540.5,same value getting from {!Get_CA.Current_Value__pc} as they are the same field of the same record.

Even in the Decision they're equal even though they have different values.(Underline red in image)
Any ideas this happened? Thanks.

[image: Flow Image]

Comment: Could you please add the expected output to your question.